# Why do we write some part of os in assembly and some part in high level language like c?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, operating-system

In implementing operating system except very small part is written in assembly while most part is written in high level languages such as C/c++
What is the part that is written in assembly and why do we write it and why most of the code is written in high level languages

Comment: This question is too chatty for SO. Questions should be about specific programming problems which have specific answers. Any answers here are likely to be opinions.

Comment: Short answer: Writing in C/C++ can be easer, but not everything can be written in C/C++.

Comment: Good question, no reason to downvote. Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn’t a suitable format for such rather broad questions.

Comment: Because no one has created hardware that can interpret/execute C code directly.

Comment: Basically, there are certain things, having to do with "talking" to the CPU registers and registers in the I/O interface, that you cannot do from a standard language like C.  There are some special-purpose languages like PL/S that and some variants of C that allow inline assembly or the specification of registers to be used, but standard C (or whatever) simply can't do things like twiddle the task register bits.

Comment: @user315052: There is also no hardware that can interpret/execute assembly code directly. Clearly the inability of the hardware to execute a language is not an impediment to writing software in that language and executing it on the hardware.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I just mean you can put machine code in memory, and the right processor can execute it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - But there was a direct-execution FORTRAN (almost) computer at one time.  (Can't remember the name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am not sure that C qualify as a *high* level language (IMHO, it is a low level one; Haskell, Ocaml, ... are higher level than C).

Then, not everything inside an operating system kernel is implementable in portable C. Hardware dependent stuff (interrupt handling, scheduling, paging, access to hardware I/O ports ...) usually requires some assembly code.

(You could perhaps embed the code with `asm` keyword in C, but that does not count as portable C).

Comment: C : All the power of assembly language, with the flexibility of... assembly language.

Comment: No; not all the power of assembly: for instance, `longjmp` is not implementable in portable *C*, it needs some assembly

Comment: Its a comp.rec.humor joke from a *long* time ago (apparently too long ago).

Comment: C is quite high-level. It provides abstractions that are a pain to implement in assembly. Despite of memory management questionsc, pointers, etc., it is still way above, for example, raw assembler.

Comment: C is just high-level assembly language :-)

Comment: Thnx for the instant answer but still it was partial you just explained why we use assembly in OS.

Comment: I'd also say assembly is used in particular portions of the code for performance

Comment: I am not at all sure of that anymore, at least in new code; processors are horribly complex these days, and optimizing compilers emit better code than a human can write today.

Comment: Why would you answer and vote to close the same answer? I don't get it.

Comment: I often do that. Why should it be wrong? I can evaluate that a question is out of topic on SO but still answer it!

Comment: I don't know, feels a bit two-faced to me :)